# Json Deserialize into object C# Json.net

Tags: c#, api, serialization, json.net, restsharp

I am trying to Deserialize a json string into a class, however, the property keeps coming up null.

```
IRestResponse companyResponse = companyClient.Execute(companyRequest);
Company companyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Company>(companyResponse.Content);

public class Company
{
     public string id { get; set; }
}
```

The company get request pulls in several other pieces of data, but I am only interested in the ID value. From what I have read on this site as well as on the internet, the above should work.

EDIT: The returning get

```
"{\"companies\":[{\"id\":\"7f91f557-4d12-486e-ba89-09c46c8a56b7\",\"name\":\"storEDGE Demo\",\"contact_email\":\"\",\"contact_phone\":\"5555555555\",\"rental_center_subdomain\":null,\"websites\":[{\"provider\":\"storedge\",\"provider_id\":\"storedgedemo\"}],\"eligible_for_voyager_website\":[{\"provider_exists\":true,\"api_association_exists\":true}],\"sales_demo\":true,\"pusher_channel\":\"private-company-7f91f5574d12486eba8909c46c8a56b7\",\"address\":{\"id\":\"b4afccb5-4d5d-4ccd-9965-67280cb868c5\",\"address1\":\"1234 storEDGE St. \",\"address2\":\"\",\"city\":\"Kansas City\",\"state\":\"MO\",\"postal\":\"66205\",\"country\":\"US\",\"full_address\":\"1234 storEDGE St. , Kansas City, MO 66205\",\"latitude\":null,\"longitude\":null,\"time_zone_id\":\"America/Chicago\",\"time_zone_offset\":\"-05:00\",\"invalid_data\":false,\"label\":\"Home\"}},{\"id\":\"249f62c7-64fb-4e12-ac91-9a4a30c1ab1c\",\"name\":\"SafeStor Insurance Company\",\"contact_email\":\"ponderosainsurance@gmail.com\",\"contact_phone\":\"\",\"rental_center_subdomain\":null,\"websites\":[],\"eligible_for_voyager_website\":[{\"provider_exists\":false,\"api_association_exists\":false}],\"sales_demo\":false,\"pusher_channel\":\"private-company-249f62c764fb4e12ac919a4a30c1ab1c\",\"address\":{\"id\":\"aa5a7775-1eb9-4fc6-8b91-b2179b9fd1fb\",\"address1\":\"5901 Catalina\",\"address2\":\"\",\"city\":\"Fairway\",\"state\":\"KS\",\"postal\":\"66205\",\"country\":\"US\",\"full_address\":\"5901 Catalina, Fairway, KS 66205\",\"latitude\":null,\"longitude\":null,\"time_zone_id\":\"America/Chicago\",\"time_zone_offset\":\"-05:00\",\"invalid_data\":false,\"label\":\"Home\"}}],\"meta\":{\"pagination\":{\"current_page\":1,\"total_pages\":1,\"per_page\":100,\"total_entries\":2,\"previous_page\":null,\"next_page\":null},
```

Comment: please post the json contents

Comment: @RicardoPontual posted! sorry It's a mess to read though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deseiralizing the JSON to the wrong type.

The JSON shown is a JSON object with an array property, which I would assume is the collection of companies.

Use the following model

```
public class RootObject {
    public Company[] companies { get; set; }
}
```

From there you can

```
var json = companyResponse.Content;
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
Company[] companies = result.companies;
```

Comment: Yes, in the provided get, that's for a demo company, but in production, there were be tens if not hundreds of companies that will be provided.  Trying out your method here and seeing how it goes! I appreciate your response.

Comment: It works! question, do I need to have it as a rootobject name? or Can i specify RootObjectCompany to it? I have several other objects I will need to do this for and will need to specify which is what.

Comment: @ggiaquin16 You can name it what ever you like This was just an example.

Comment: Awesome, I was wondering because the built in json to class converter had previously created somethig named rootobject before (without really understanding why I deleted it), I will need to go back and add it but making sure it wasn't something that needed that name specifically or not.

Comment: @ggiaquin16 the name is used in examples more to get the point across that you are dealing with nested objects with this one being the top most one. A lot of tools follow the same naming pattern

Answer (score 1):

Your Deserialization is expecting json content of object with property `id` which is clearly not the content that is passing.

By the file content you posted, you should add another class and change deserialization type.

```
public class Response
{
    [JsonProperty("companies")
    public Company[] Companies { get; set; }
}

var companiesResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(companyResponse.Content);
```

Comment: Orel, thank you so much for your response, Trying this out as well as the other provided answer! I appreciate it.

Comment: This was fairly easy to implement, short and sweet and it worked! Thank you a ton for the response.